# Trajectory equation for object fired horizontally from a given height

Tags: math, box2d, game-physics

Does anyone know the equation to get the current *x* position and the current *y* position of a projectile with gravity and mass figured in? The object is fired horizontally from a given height *h*, with initial velocity *v*.

Comment: Do you have any other knowns?

Comment: It would depend on the force the projectile is launched with, the angle, and various other things. If you do a little more research, this may be a suitable question on physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: but then, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile) has a fairly detailed article on the subject already; so it's probably considered trivial reference.

Comment: I have the start x, start y, velocity, and i can get the time for the current position.

Comment: You're also going to need to know the initial launch angle.

Comment: @NineBlindEyes then you do not have enough. the problem is not solvable.

Comment: The angle is zero (not angled just fired straight out from a specific height).

Comment: is it fired across a flat surface?

Comment: @NineBlindEyes, I've [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12645114/revisions) your question to include information you provided in the comments. In case I did misunderstand your question, please edit it yourself to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trajectory will be a parabola. If you're fire the projectile horizontally (i.e. in positive *x* direction) at height *y*<sub>0</sub>, then you're entering the parabola at its vertex, for which I'll use coordinates (*x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>0</sub>). Ignoring friction, the horizontal component of your velocity will always equal the initial velocity, whereas the vertical velocity will increrase linearily with time. Intergrating that gives you the position for a given time *t* as:

- *x* = *x*<sub>0</sub> + *vt*
- *y* = *y*<sub>0</sub> − *gt*<sup>2</sup>/2

In the second equation, *g* denotes the [gravitational acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration) of 9.81­ m/s<sup>2</sup>. Unless you consider friction, the mass of the object has no impact at all, as the higher gravitational force is compensated by the greater inertia. The equations obviously assume that positive *y* is *up*, and the gravity pulls *down*.